EF Core 8 - Database Update -> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type
I am creating my database via code first. I can do a database add migration without errors, but when I am calling:
dotnet ef database update --project .\BKR.DB --startup-project .\BKR.Web --context BKRContext
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'BKRContext'. The exception 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
I get the above error
Please find my code "setup" as attached image.
